# Is it bad to force the use of .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I noticed that most of the frameworks (CodeIgniter for example), do provide a default .htaccess file but don't force its use.

1. Why don't they force its use?
2. Does .htaccess work on all servers?
3. What are the alternatives?

Comment: The real question is why *should* they force its use?

Comment: @Juhana, To block the access to the framework folders for example, instead of that annoying `if (!isset(a_constant_that_must_exists)) { exit(); }`. Or to avoid those `index.html` all over the folder structure that just print (Directory access is forbitten).

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with .htaccess. Framework folders are already outside the document root (or should be).

Comment: @Juhana, In CodeIgniter it's not, just for example. We have `/index.php` and then `/system/`.

Comment: That's a shame. I'd use something else, then.

Comment: "For the best security, both the system and any application folders should be placed above web root so that they are not directly accessible via a browser." (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html)

Comment: how would you "force its use" exactly? also, all framework files should be located outside of the public tree as Juhana said. htaccess works on apache servers.

Comment: typically you would add an include path to the framework root which would be outside of the public folder.

Comment: Still, why was my question down voted? It seems to be a question to me, it seems to fit SO to me, it doesn't seems to be spam to me. So what's the deal?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli The title is very bad and the question too broad. If someone would ask me at random whether it's bad to use .htaccess, I'd say yes because it only works for Apache, has a performance hit and may cause issues if disabled (i.e. careless upgrading)

Comment: @Lekensteyn, Ok. Next time you down vote a question please be clear it was you. Anonymous down votes are very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.htaccess` files only work on apache servers. When using other servers it highly depends on what you want to do - but usually you need to edit the server config to rewrite URLs, block directories, etc.

The fact that frameworks *need* .htaccess files is actually an annoying problem from the PHP world since 99% of all applications are stored inside the document root, thus giving users  HTTP access to all their files unless they are somehow restricted (e.g. via .htaccess). On the other hand, if you have a WSGI-based python application, you usually store it outside the document root and "mount" it to a certain folder in the document root - this way not a single file can be accessed directly via HTTP.

Comment: Let's say we are dealing with a framework that requires: "PHP 5.3.3+ and Apache" to work. Can I be 90% sure that my .htaccess file will work?

Comment: If it's for security or otherwise a very important feature, do not rely on it. `.htaccess` can be disabled with a directive like `AllowOverride none` which is in fact the default on Ubuntu server.

Comment: Yes, you can assume that either your htaccess will work or if not, people disabled htaccess files on purpose and will know that they need to copy&paste the contents into their vhost config.

Comment: ThiefMaster is simplifying somewhat.  Use of .htaccess is pretty common outside of M$ IIS which uses its own web.config standard (it does roughly the same but in a way entirely different to everyone else).  However, there are annoying subtle differences between the various `.htaccess` implementations. IMO, it's sort of "render unto Caesar" issue.  The app should contain app logic and Web service level accesses control and mapping belongs in the web service layer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, yes it is the default if you are building your VM images, but can you name a single share hosting LAMP offering that does this? :-)  No -- it's universal in this market sector.

Comment: @TerryE If you are writing scripts which may be used on shared hosting accounts, it's a good thing not to lose features without a `.htaccess` file ;) But no, I can't recall a shared hosting company that disallows .htaccess.

Comment: If you want to use clean URLs you pretty much have to use .htaccess or another way to force all requests through a single PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

1) I have to agree with Juhana. The question is: why should they force it? There is no need to restrict a framework with such a thing.

2) I heard that they are not working on IIS Server, where you have to translate it in special config files.

3) It depends on what you're doing. But because of the fact you do not really need .htaccess files, just let them be is a possible alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Because it does not work on all servers (esp. hosting providers can restrict its use) and there is really no good reason to enforce it.
2. See #1. Also, they tend to not work in the same way if you're not running Apache.
3. Very wide question. If you're running Apache it's pretty much the only way to configure the server while not being a privileged user. If you're not running Apache, it's dependent on the specific web server.

Some useful links;

- [Apache htaccess to nginx rewriterule converter](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/)
- [How to translate htaccess to IIS web.config](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/)
- [How to work around lighttpd's lack of directory specific config](http://diaryproducts.net/about/web_servers/lighttpd/htaccess_lighttpd)

Comment: 3), yep, I figured that out by myself. The question then is: Depending on the specific web server, what are the alternatives? Can you list them or link me to them?

Comment: 3) What do you need it for? For nginx for example, you'd have to edit the nginx config (e.g. Basic auth) or php.ini (for PHP settings)

Comment: @JeffPigarelli Added some info on a few web servers and how they relate to htaccess to my answer.